# Dataframe transformation pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| A | type | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | B | 20 |
| second | B | 30 |
| first | C | 200 |
| second | C | 300 |

I need to get it to look like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | 20 | 200 |
| second | 30 | 300 |

How do I do this using Pandas? I tried using transpose, but couldn't get it to this exact table.

```
df = df.pivot('A','type')
df.columns = [x[1] for x in list(df.columns)]
df.reset_index()
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: The correct link for the pivot table functionality: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['first', 'second', 'first', 'second'],
                   'type': ['B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                   'val': [20, 30, 200, 300]})

pd.pivot_table(df, values='val', index='A', columns='type')
```